# How to calculate wlan0 interface speed

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

When, I try to cat the speed file, in /sys/class/net I get the following error

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/speed 
cat: /sys/class/net/wlan0/speed: Invalid argument #throws error
```

Whereas, for eth0 it shows

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/speed
1000
```

Can I know the reason for the error for wlan alone. Also the duplex is unkown for wlan0 but the carrier is set to 1?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the output of `iwconfig <interface>`.

Comment: yeah. It's working thanks. Can I know from which file does iwconfig calculates

Answer (score -1):

You can use all of these commands (I recommend `ethtool`)

`dmesg | grep <interface>`

`mii-tool`

`ethtool <interface>`

Comment: ethtool just outputs link detected: yes

Comment: nothing else but for eth0 it gives speed and other stuffs